# Jquery: "find" of range attributes (Between 2 numbers)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an issue with JQuery i couldn't solved..

i have this line:

```
var $price = $data.find('li[price=' + $max + ']');
```

That find the Attribute "price" That equal to Var "$max"

Now, basically, I have 2 numbers, $min And $max, And i need that "find" will check if the attribute is between this 2 numbers..

For Example:

```
  <ul class="ourHolder">
    <li price="200">
    <img src="img1.jpg">
    </li>
    <li price="300">
    <img src="img2.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>

    <script>

// get and assign the ourHolder element to the
    // $holder varible for use later
  var $holder = $('ul.ourHolder');

  // clone all items within the pre-assigned $holder element
  var $data = $holder.clone();
    var $min = 100;
    var $min = 400;
    var $price = $data.find('li[price=' + $max + ']'); //Not sure what to do here
    </script>
```

Should return both `<li>` tags.. (Both are Between 100 and 400).

New edit:

I added this:

```
var price = data.find('li').filter(function() {
   var price = parseInt($(this).data('price')); // i think here it doesn't find nothing
    return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
});
```

But i returns nothing :(

Thank you!!

Comment: I suspect the problem is that "price" is not a valid HTML attribute.

Comment: Hi, just added the $data var to the code, I hope now its more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should be using `data` attributes, as just making up your own attributes will render your code invalid. Secondly you can use `filter()` to find elements based on a more complex set of rules. Try this:

```
<li data-price="200">
    <img src="img1.jpg">
</li>
<li data-price="300">
    <img src="img2.jpg">
</li>
```

```js
var minPrice = 100;
var maxPrice = 400;
var $matchingLi = $data.find('li').filter(function() {
    var price = parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
    return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
});
```

Comment: This will work if "$data" is something appropriate; we don't know what it is, however.

Comment: @Pointy very true. I assumed it was a parent element as OP was already using it to `find()` his `li` elements in the example.

Comment: you are right, just added the $data var to the code, I hope now its more clearly, The "Filter" as it now doesn't seems to work.. Thank you all anyway.. any other ideas?